# Symfony 3 catch Soap connection error

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, soap

I´m trying to catch when I get a Soap connection problem
This is my service

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\Usuarios;
use AppBundle\Entity\Roles;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;

class ADService
{
    private $em;
    private $encoderFactory;
    private $URLService = 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX?wsdl';
    private $soap;

    public function __construct (EntityManagerInterface $em, EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;
        try {
            $this->soap = new \SoapClient($this->URLService, array('trace' => 0, 'exceptions' => true));
        } 
        catch (SoapFault $sf) { 
            echo "Soapfault"; 
            $this->soap = null;
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) { 
            echo "Exception"; 
            $this->soap = null;
        }
    }
```

But this throw me an error

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX?wsdl' : failed to load external
>   entity "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX?wsdl"

How can I catch a soap connection error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: try `catch (\Exception $e)` reason: currently you try to catch AppBundle\Service\SoapFault and AppBundle\Service\Exception, which most likely is not thrown

Comment: Yes, so what can I do? Or how can I get the connection error?

Comment: `catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e->faultcode, $e->faultstring, $e->faultactor, $e->detail, $e->_name, $e->headerfault);
}`

Comment: hi, tranks for your comment. 2 thins: non of the e-> were found and now catch the SoapFault error but "Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
 (FatalErrorException) " page still shows after render page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I made to solve my problem

```
    $file_headers = @get_headers($this->URLService);
    if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
        $this->soap = null;
        return;
    } else {
        $this->soap = new \SoapClient($this->URLService);
    }
```

If anyone have a better solution, please post it.